# Attempting to assert 500 error, but response is null when conditions are met

Tags: groovy, automation, spock

When I automated this I came to know that the 500 error that is thrown is given by server. But at our code level we have handled the exception and the response =null

So when I tried to assert with response.status==500 it fails as the response is altogether null.

```
package test

import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import net.sf.json.JSON

import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class EventsAPITest extends GebReportingSpec{

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("EventsAPITest");

    @Unroll
    def "Call calendar event for Invalid Location id 110 throws groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException"() {
        given:
        RESTClient restClient = new RESTClient("https://test-api2.club-os.com")
        def response=restClient.get(path: '/authenticate',requestContentType: JSON,query:[
            'username': 'apiuser',
            'password':'apipassword',
        ])
        def authToken=response.data.token
        logger.info"Token:" +authToken
        restClient.defaultRequestHeaders['Authorization'] = authToken
        def locationId=110
        when:
        response=restClient.get(path: '/locations/'+locationId+'/events',requestContentType: JSON, query:[
            'startTimeStartAt': '2018-05-25T17:00:00.000Z',
            'startTimeEndAt':'2018-06-01T17:00:00.000Z',
            'eventTypeId' : 2                      ])
        then:
        thrown groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException
        logger.info"Response: "+ response
        //  assert response.data.errorMessage=="Error"
        assert  response.status == 500
        //assert    response.status == 500
        //  assert  response.data.errorMessage == "An unknown error occurred"
    }
```

I would like to be able to assert a 500 error and have that returned.

Answer (score 0):

This is not spock-specific. Your code throws an exception, therefore it cannot return a value.

**UPDATE after kriegaex's advice in the comments.**

By assigning the result of the `thrown groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException` expression to a variable, you can access the exception's state. This exception's API is documented here: http://javadox.com/org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder/http-builder/0.6/groovyx/net/http/HttpResponseException.html.

You can access the `statusCode` property directly, and you have a `response` property too. That's everything you need to test your conditions.

This is the resulting code:

```
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import net.sf.json.JSON

import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class EventsAPITest extends GebReportingSpec{

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("EventsAPITest");

@Unroll
    def "Call calendar event for Invalid Location id 110 throws groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException"() {
        given:
        RESTClient restClient = new RESTClient("https://test-api2.club-os.com")
        def response=restClient.get(path: '/authenticate',requestContentType: JSON,query:[
            'username': 'apiuser',
            'password':'apipassword',
        ])
        def authToken=response.data.token
        logger.info"Token:" +authToken
        restClient.defaultRequestHeaders['Authorization'] = authToken
        def locationId=110
        when:
        response=restClient.get(path: '/locations/'+locationId+'/events',requestContentType: JSON, query:[
            'startTimeStartAt': '2018-05-25T17:00:00.000Z',
            'startTimeEndAt':'2018-06-01T17:00:00.000Z',
            'eventTypeId' : 2                      ])
        then:
        //Here, assign the exception to a variable.
        def e= thrown groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException
        logger.info"Response: "+ e.response
        //  assert response.data.errorMessage=="Error"
        assert  e.response.status == 500
        //assert    response.status == 500
        //  assert  response.data.errorMessage == "An unknown error occurred"
    }
```

Comment: While your answer looks correct, some more explanation would be good. I had to copy both code snippets from question and answer and diff them in order to notice what you changed. Actually you are assigning the exception from the `thrown` statement to a local variable and utilising its properties.

Comment: Some more hints to Daniel: (1) Your test is not a browser test, you should extend `spock.lang.Specification`, not `geb.spock.GebReportingSpec`, otherwise a browser will be started for no good reason. You use a headless REST client. (2) You should make `groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException` an import and use the simple class name in the test. (3) In the `then:` block you don't need `assert`, just write a condition like `e.message == "An unknown error occurred"`.